# How do you Calculate Multiple Pages to a Grand Total in LiveCycle?

Tags: excel, acrobat, livecycle

I am not a programmer but I have to create an expense form for traveling.  It has to be in PDF format (preferably Adobe Acrobat editable).  I created the form with Excel and exported it to Adobe but, of course, the formulas do not transfer.

I have 3 pages that are identical for calculating travel expenses with the only difference being there is one extra cell on the first page that calculates totals from each page to a grand total.  Sounds easy.  All the pages calculate individually with no problem but I cannot reference the totals from the individual pages to the first page where the grand total is.

I am using Adobe LiveCycle because it "simplifies" the programming process for people like me.  It has worked great so far but this is the only thing problem I am having and the only thing holding me from using the form.

All three pages are in the same document.  When I use FormCalc for the totals within each page, it works great:

topmostSubform.Page1.P1TotalGrand::calculate - (FormCalc, client)
$=P1MileageTotal+P1TransAirTotal+P1CarRenTotal+P1HotelTotal+P1AllowTotal+P1PhoneTotal+P1MIETotal+P1BusMealTotal+P1OtherTotal

If I go to the next page, it looks like this:

topmostSubform.Page2.P1TotalGrand::calculate - (FormCalc, client)
$=P1MileageTotal+P1TransAirTotal+P1CarRenTotal+P1HotelTotal+P1AllowTotal+P1PhoneTotal+P1MIETotal+P1BusMealTotal+P1OtherTotal

I just want to be able to add them together.  When I try, it doesn't recognize the 2nd page and I don't know why.  The form is pretty basic and I would really appreciate any help.  If you need any additional information, I'll be glad to oblige.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it. There should be many ways and I am a newbie too so here are two ways...

1. If you want grand total of 2 pages - does not matter on which page you want it, the formula should be like

   ```
   topmostSubform.Page1.P1GREATTotalGrand::calculate - (FormCalc, client)
   $=P1TotalGrand+P2TotalGrand
   ```

   The trick is to select both by **press and hold Ctrl Key**, then select the field you want to select rather then type in. this should solve the problem.
2. If you want the total to be at page one. 
   Make the `P2GreatTotalGrand` to be a **global data**  and create the same data field on page one  and add this new one and one already on page one to get the grand total on page one.